# how to add existing key to openssh on windows?

Tags: git, putty, openssh

I have been using putty/plink/pageant + tortoiseGIT on many computers, and found it difficult and painful and does not work with eclipse.

So I decided to install tortoiseSVN and windowsGIT selecting the openssh version instead of the putty version.

I have an existing key installed in github, and I have the **ppk** file which was generated which I would had to manually load each time I wanted to use it in pageant.

But Now I am stuck. How do I do this using openssh? What is the openSSH equivalent of pageant?

I suspect I have to convert the ppk into id_rsa.pub or simlar, but what do I do with them to make them usable on the local machine?

Do I have to install something called openSSH in the same way I installed putty? Does it have something like pageant?

Or should I give up and go back to using putty for SSH (and having to manually load keys every time)

Edit 1.
Haven't found anything in 2 hours of googling this. I'm going to take a wild guess that openssh is not something I need to install, but is something which came with git install.  I'm going to guess that because there is no mention of it, that windows uses the same scheme as Unix, i.e. put the keys ~/.ssh/...
So I used puttygen to load my ppk, then "export openSSH key".  Then I tried saving it as both ~/.ssh/mykey.rsa and mykey.dsa (no idea which one it should be). This did not work - tortoise git still says

```
"could not read from remote repository"
```

The problem I guess is that there is no way to know if puttygen is exporting the public or private key - it doesn't give you the option.

I have also tried saving as id_rsa and id_dsa, no luck.

Comment: If you don't use putty to `ssh` to your hosts, what do you use now? OpenSSH has client.There are several flavors of it. Some are Win32 others are cygwin. Check which client is supported by your app. OpenSSH usually stores the private keys (id_rsa, id_dsa, identity) under $HOME/.ssh directory. And yes, you do have to convert your .ppk key into id_rsa private key file. You don't need to generate the public key because it is probably already registered on your git and svn server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Some background

[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com) has no equivalent of pageant.  Well, almost.  It has an `ssh-agent.exe` program ([man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent&sektion=1)) and an accompanying `ssh-add.exe` program ([man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-add&sektion=1)) to add keys to the agent.

The unfortunate (for Windows) thing is that the workflow assumed by `ssh-agent` is like this:

1. You run it, it prints some information about how it can be reached (by `ssh-add`) then detaches from the terminal and goes to the background.

   The information it prints is presented in the form of a *Unix shell code* which sets some environment variables, so most of the time it's supposed to be run like this:

   ```
   eval `ssh-agent -s`
   ```

   While this sounds complicated, on any sensible Unix-like system, your Desktop Environment will make sure the SSH agent is spawned early at startup and the environment variables handed off by it are used and are inherited by all the programs later started by the user.  So it just works™ without you even noticing.
2. You run `ssh-add` to feed keys to a running instance of `ssh-agent`.

   This program locates the agent using the environment variables set on step one.
3. The SSH client tries to locate the agend using the same approach as `ssh-add` when it's about to shake hands with the server.

As you can see, this model does not need to know about graphical user environments etc so you won't get any fancy tray icon and some sort of GUIs to feed your keys to the agent.

Since this obviously doesn't play well with the way a user's session is created in Windows, PuTTY implements its own approach to provide an SSH agent, its own means to locate the running agent and its own protocol to talk with it.

#### What you can do about this

1. Continue using PuTTY.

   I don't use Eclipse but I know it uses [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) to work with the repository and talk with remote servers.  So if you'll find a way to tell JGit how to use your own SSH client program to set up an SSH tunnel (like Git for Windows does with its `GIT_SSH` environment variable) you'll be able to use Eclipse with PuTTY.
2. Forfeit the security of your SSH key and work without the need for SSH agent.

   For this, you might use PuTTY's `puttygen.exe` to convert the SSH key in the native PuTTY's format to the one suitable for OpenSSH *without* providing an encryption password—and hence obtaining an unencrypted key—and then supply that key to OpenSSH: either by placing it under `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` and naming it `id_rsa` (yeah, `id_rsa` without any extension) or create an `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` configuration file and specify there where your key is located. Refer to [this manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) for its format.

Comment: Thanks for this great reply.  I tried loading my ppk and converting it to openssh using puttygen. It said "are you sure you want to sve without a phassphrase" (i said YES!), but then it does still require the passphrase, i.e. every git command (which uses openSSH) still requires me to enter the passphrase every time. How did you manage to strip out the passphrase?

Comment: Also, if you have to save the file as id_rsa, how do you every have more than one key on a machine?

Comment: @JohnLittle, regarding the key -- works for me. I runned `puttygen` loaded my key (providing the password) then removed the passphrase from both the fields in the dialog and navigated to the export command; it warned me but saved the unencrypted key. To verify that: run Git Bash (you have it installed if you have Git for Windows installed) and there run `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` followed by `ssh-add` -- it should print it has just added the key. Finish the agent by running `ssh-agent -k`.

Comment: You are correct, I got it working.  Now I am very happy.  Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually got it working, after reading about 50 posts and trying a lot of options.

All the articles i found on setting up git on windows either use plink, or generate a new cert (and dont mention how to install it locally).  Using an existing one requires this:

1) load up your ppk in puttygen

2) in the Conversions menu select "export OpenSSH key"

3) save the file in  ~/.ssh/id_rsa, e.g. c:\Users\me.ssh\id_rsa

Problems:

1) if you want to add a second key, I have no idea where you can put it.

2) it still requires that you enter a passphrase EVERY time you do a git command.  There 
seems to be no way to remember it.  With pageant, you can have the key loaded once, then it remembers it till you shut down. I tried createing a _netrc file, but this did not work (I guess it only works if you use plink, not openssh).

I cant see why anyone would chose to use openssh over plink.

Comment: As to problems: 1) the OpenSSH client's config file allows to specify the location of the key file for each host you access, or an alias to such host; 2) That's because the agent is not used, so the client locates the key each time and asks for a passphrase to read it. A way to deal with it is to use an unencrypted key.

Comment: OK, all the instructions above dont work.  I had some other files in the .ssh dir which made it work. I have now deleted those.  When I load my ppk, and export to openSSH and call it .ssh/id_rsa, git bash cant connect.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: This might be due to you having deleted the `known_hosts` file so the SSH client does not trust any of the servers anymore. Try running `ssh your_git_user@your_git_server` from Git Bash after having set the key file up and when the SSH client asks whether you trust the server you're connecting to, answer "yes".  This question will not be asked again.

Comment: I didnt delete the knownhosts, only other attempted types of key saves.  I tried ssh mygituser@githum.com and it comes back with "permission denied (plublickey)"

Comment: OK, think I got there, i deleted the 3 keys defined in github, and started again.  I saved the openssh version of my ppk, deleting the phrase first, and now I can use git without a password, I am very very happy.

Comment: to use another for example.com domain, open `%UserProfile%/.ssh/`, open `config` file and add these lines: `Host example.com`, (indent with 2 spaces) `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/anotherKeyFilename`